# Assigning priority to custom data attributes in css

Tags: html, css, custom-data-attribute

This seems super basic, but I'm trying to create css priority for HTML elements that include a custom data value. The value is used for an infrequent context that requires modification of core styles. I haven't been able to combine id's with data selectors successfully. Is this even possible?

Any guidance on how to create priority over `<div #id="x">` with `<div id="x" data-value="y">`?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean for the first one to be `<div id="x">`?

Answer (score 1):

You can  use the presence of an attribute in a CSS rule:

```
#x {
    /* default CSS here */
}

#x[data-value] {
    /* CSS for items with the attribute here */
}
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for reference.

But, you may have a problem if both of these elements exist in the same page because you should only ever have one object with a given ID in the page so you probably need to move to using classes instead of an id.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/nCD3m/

Comment: Having an ID doesn't guarantee that an element either has or doesn't have that data attribute, even if it's the only one in the page.

Comment: @BoltClock - the OP asked how to override a CSS rule for an element that has the custom attribute.  That's what this answer does.  I don't understand what you think is the problem.

Comment: You said "But, you have a problem because you should only ever have one object with a given ID in the page" and I'm saying that's not really a problem.

Comment: @BoltClock - other than the fact that it's illegal HTML you mean?  I think good answers should point out other issues that the code has which is what I did.  You can see in my demo how I made it work just fine with a common class name which is legal HTML.

Comment: Yes, and I'm not faulting you for that. I'm merely pointing out that it's reasonable and not problematic to target an element both by its ID and an attribute, even if the page correctly assigned it only to a single element at a time, because that element may not always have that attribute on that page, and the OP wants to account for both cases. But I just reread the question and it says "HTML elements", so for all we know the OP might indeed have multiple elements with the same ID which, of course as we know, is illegal.

Comment: @BoltClock - OK, I've amended my answer to make my comment about ids clearer though it does sound like the OP has multiple elements in the page.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The issue was basically how to separate an identical condition in varying contexts via CSS. I hit a challenge anytime I had to style a child element to a div. The basic solution was to not separate selectors, so where a statement might have been #IDfoo [ATTRIBUTE] child-element, child-element#IDFOO[ATTRIBUTE] worked.

Comment: @jivers - Having no space between selector elements means that a single object must satisfy all the criteria.  This works such as `.photo.selected` or `#foo[data-value]` or any sequence of selectors.